# What is the meaning of 'as likely to be female as male' in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> Today, the average video game player will be thirty something, ***as
>   likely to be female as male***, will play on multiple devices and can
>   come from anywhere in the world.

My understanding of this is the number of female game players is equal to the number of male players, but I am not sure. I have another understanding about this, which is females also play video games just as males do. Which one is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Your first understanding is correct. It means that 50% of video game players are female and 50% male.

Comment: Best if you could provide links to sources.. :)

Comment: How would I source this? AFAIK there's no canonical source on the correct interpretation of every English phrase.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/110567/as-likely-to-as